# Why no window is being shown despite no error or warnings

Tags: user-interface, delphi, lazarus, freepascal

I am trying following code for a GUI to show 2 identical windows. I am using show rather than showmodal:

```
program RnTFormclass;
{$mode delphi}
uses
    //cthreads, // for linux only.
    Interfaces, Forms, StdCtrls;

type
    RnTForm = class(TForm)
    private
        wnd: TForm;
        btn: TButton;
    public
        constructor create;
        procedure showit; 
    end; 

constructor RnTForm.create;
    begin
        //Application.Initialize;  //removed.
        wnd := TForm.Create(Application);
        with wnd do begin
            Height  := 300;
            Width   := 400;
            Position:= poDesktopCenter;
            Caption := 'LAZARUS WND';
            end;
        btn := TButton.Create(wnd);
            with btn do begin
            SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
            Caption := 'Click Me';
            Parent  := wnd;
            end;
    end;

procedure RnTForm.showit;
    begin
        wnd.Show;
    end;

var 
    myform1, myform2: RnTForm;

begin
    // create windows: 
    myform1 := RnTForm.Create;
    myform2 := RnTForm.Create;
    // show windows: 
    myform1.showit;
    myform2.showit;
end.
```

I want two identical windows to show/open up. Though the program runs without any error or warning, not even one window is shown. 
The program just terminates.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, Application.initialize is being called twice and not run. I have commented out Application.initialize and the code still does not open up any of the window. (It does open windows one by one if `show` is replaced by `showModal`).

Main question is how to keep window open after `show`?

Comment: I don't know Linux and Lazarus, but from a Windows/Delphi perspective, your program seems to lack a message loop. Also, I think calling `Application.Initialize` in a form constructor is wrong.

Comment: I would suspect you need to call `Application.Initialize` very early (and only once, not one time per created `RnTForm`!) and then something like `Application.Run` to start the message loop. Further: You seem not to run the inherited `TForm` constructor in the `RnTForm` constructor. [Again, these comments are from a Win32/Delphi perspective.]

Comment: That's a really weird way of implementing a GUI. Are you sure that calling Applicatoin.Initialize in the constructor is right? After all, it gets called twice this way! And why do you create additional instances of TForm and show these rather than simply using the instances of RnTForm you create anyway? Also, there is no call to Application.Run, so the forms may be created and even logically be shown, but the program terminates immediately after that and so they will disappear before they are even drawn.

Comment: Start with the gui template that comes with Lazarus. Not really much point analysing this broken code with no message loop.

Comment: Program execution remains the same after removing Application.initialize. Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: @rno: Of course it doesn't work; it has no message loop. Since I don't know Linux/Lazarus, I cannot help you with the details, but I think David's suggestion is good: surely Lazarus can create an empty GUI app for you, so you get the basic structure right.

Comment: Pl see my own answer here.

Answer (score -3):

Taking suggestions from comments, I got it working by following main method:

```
begin
    Application.Initialize; 
    // create windows: 
    myform1 := RnTForm.Create;
    myform2 := RnTForm.Create;
    // show windows: 
    myform1.showit;
    myform2.showit;
    Application.run; 
end.
```

Now both the windows appear and I can click and work on any of them.

However, on closing both the windows, the program still keeps running in background. An exit button with its click function needs to be added.

Comment: Now at least you got a message loop. But this almost certainly isn't the right way to do it, and will likely cause a number of issues. You have discovered one of them, but I suspect there are more (and if not, there may be additional problems with the next Lazarus RTL version, the next version of Windows, the next button you add to the form, etc.). I really do believe the right thing is to change to the standard approach. We don't want to write software that "mostly works (under favourable conditions)". We want robust software that does things right and always work.

Comment: If I had to use an application that cannot be closed by closing the visible windows using their title bar close buttons, system menus, Alt+F4, etc., I'd be a bit annoyed. Again, I am very sorry I don't know Linux/Lazarus and thus cannot give you the details about the right way. :/

Comment: Why would the process close? Normally the process closes when the main form closes. You don't have a main form. If you want the process to close when both forms are closed, implement code to do so.